# How to center crop Images in Fabricjs?

Tags: image, canvas, fabricjs

I'm able to add Images to the canvas using Fabric.js.

However, I have a fixed width & height for the image box.

The images will be added dynamically and their width and height would vary.

To make it consistent, I want to center crop the Image to fit the width and height of the image box.

How do I do that using Fabric.js?

Sample Images

[image: Place Holder Image]

[image: Dynamic Image 1]

[image: Dynamic Image 2]

Here is my code:

```js
let newObj = {
  "version": "4.6.0",
  "objects": [{
    type: 'image',
    version: '4.6.0',
    originX: 'left',
    originY: 'top',
    left: 24,
    top: 24,
    width: 250,
    height: 250,
    fill: 'rgb(0,0,0)',
    scaleX: 0.49,
    scaleY: 0.49,
    visible: true,
    backgroundColor: '',
    fillRule: 'nonzero',
    paintFirst: 'fill',
    globalCompositeOperation: 'source-over',
    src: 'https://logo.clearbit.com/mircrosoft.com?size=400',
    crossOrigin: null,
    filters: [],
    scaleToWidth: 250,
    scaleToHeight: 250
  }],
  "background": "#000000"
}

var canvas1 = new fabric.StaticCanvas("a", { width: 600, height: 400 });

canvas1.loadFromJSON(newObj, function() {
  canvas1.renderAll();
});
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/521/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="a"></canvas>
```

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: @HelderSepulveda added my code

Comment: I changed your code to a code snippet that way everyone can run and see the image, I don't think the `stream` was relevant to reproduce your issue so I removed that part to keep it minimal

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you that instead of cropping you should scale the original to fit the size you need, that way it works for big and small images, and it's a simple calculation.

In your sample you have hardcoded `scaleX: 0.49` not sure why that, If the original image is quite large resolution that scale won't do much and center crop will get just a fraction of the image.

On my example below I'm assuming that your image box is a square, but if not you can use:

- http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Image.html#scaleX
- http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Image.html#scaleY

```js
const canvas1 = new fabric.StaticCanvas("a", {width: 300, height: 200});
const image_url = 'https://logo.clearbit.com/mircrosoft.com?size=400'

new fabric.Image.fromURL(image_url, img => {  
  const size = 100
  img.top = img.left = 20      
  img.scale(size/img.width);
  canvas1.add(img);
  canvas1.renderAll();
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: solid 1px red
}
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/521/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="a"></canvas>
```

---